# what could be reason for client silo not getting initialized in azure?

Tags: orleans

I am following the [HelloWorld](http://dotnet.github.io/orleans/Step-by-step-Tutorials/Front-Ends-for-Orleans-Services) example to learn how to deploy and execute an orleans app in Azure. I was able to make it work locally. When I deployed it azure, it is timing out. I followed the [azure debugging link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vs-azure-tools-debug-cloud-services-virtual-machines/) and was able to find out what is happening in the server.This is the error I am getting at the server

> w3wp.exe Error: 0 : Client.Initialize failed with exc -- One or more errors occurred.. Will try again

After some research in orleans code I [found the place](https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/blob/master/src/OrleansAzureUtils/Hosting/AzureClient.cs#L179) where this particular error is thrown. It states if the gate way is not found, this error is thrown.

I am stuck here, anyone has any pointers in how to go about trouble shoot this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow that sample: https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/tree/master/Samples/AzureWebSample
It has all the pieces you need for the deploying Hello World to Azure.
In your case it looks like you only deployed the client and not the silos.

Comment: From the solution I did publish and I was expecting to deploy everything, I guess I was wrong. How would one deploy silos separately and connect to it in the client?

Comment: I was able to make it work based on the documentation, I did not change the connection string in cloud configuration file.

Comment: Great. So everything works OK now, or do you still have questions?